# Making quaternion compatible with proprietary animation system

Tags: math, 3d, game-development

I'm working on an export tool for some game proprietary animation system. It uses quaternions for describing rotations, but for some reason it works properly only with some specific quaternions.
I think there's an issue in converting it to euler angles but without source code it's just nearly impossible to find why this happens, let alone fix it.

For example we have angle: 
`(XYZ)` `(-179.975, -0.037, -16.920)`. 
Any algorithm or implementation I've tried gives this result:
`WXYZ` `(0.000, -0.989, -0.147, 0.000)`.
If you look carefully, it has negative `X` and `Y`.

For unknown reason, as described above, that system refuses to work `(converts it to completely wrong angle)` with such quaternions (which makes it even more weird because I don't know which quaternion is 'right' and which is not).

But if you invert signs, it works just fine:
`WXYZ` `(-0.000, 0.989, 0.147, -0.000)`.
Which is a totally different quaternion but it represents the same euler angles.

I tried to trace some logic for days but it just makes no any sense.

Here's comparison between imported / exported data:
[image]

Red area is where data gets different. And the difference is only the sign.

Comment: Try something. Pick any quaternion that is accepted by the tool. Then compute the dot product of that quaternion and a quaternion that is not accepted by the tool. Take note the of sign of the dot product. Suppose it is negative. My guess is that the dot product of any valid and invalid quaternions will always be negative. While the dot product of any two valid quaternions will be possitive (the opposite). If that's true then there you go.

Comment: I should say that's very interesting idea but it wont work (I checked to be sure), the biggest problem here is that there could be almost no difference from valid / invalid quaternion. I attached another comparison picture, hope that will make it more clear.

Comment: Yep I know the difference is the sign. That is because each Euler angle correspond to two quaternions: q and -q (since q and -q represent the same rotation). So when the tool convert Euler to quaternion it is choosing one of the two. To be consistent it should be choosing quaternions with the same orientation, that's why I think the sign of the dot product should be consistent between all valid quats (lets say positive) and should switch if you dot a valid and invalid quat. So if you know a single valid quaternion and the sign that dot product should have you can solve the problem.

Comment: Since opposite sign is the same rotation, a sign difference leading to incorrect angles sounds like a bug to me. So you're asking for a workaround for a bug in an unnamed piece of proprietary software? And the little bit of sample data is a screenshot and as such not even copy&paste-able. Can you include the examples as text at the very least? As it stands I can recommend disassembling their code, to understand where the completely incorrect angles are coming from.